# how long takes to pass erc20 token to another chain in stargate

Tags: solidity, erc-20, bridge

How long takes to pass erc20 token to another chain in stargate on mainnet.

example: 1 usdt from bsc to fantom(how long takes to start transaction on destination chain?)

Answer (score 0):

if your from chain is:

1- **BSC** waits for 20 confirmation on the TX on from chain then the tx will trigger on any destination chain (does not matter which and approximately less than 2 minutes)

2- **Polygon** waits for 512 confirmation on the TX on from chain. the tech said that because of security of polygon network we add this condition(approximately between 10 minutes and 20 minutes takes)

3- **Ethereum** waits for 15 confirmation on the TX on from chain.

4- **Avalanche** waits for 12 confirmation on the TX on from chain.

4- **Arbitrum** waits for 20 confirmation on the TX on from chain.

5- **Optimism** waits for 20 confirmation on the TX on from chain.

6- **Fantom** waits for 5 confirmation on the TX on from chain.

please leave your answers or edit this answer for other chains.

if you are interested in plz vote me up :)